# TypeError: e is undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

All other browsers work perfectly fine. However, when firefox tries to execute this code:

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

it crashes and the console displays the following error:
TypeError: e is undefined

---

edit 1:

```
function clickInactiveTab() {
    $(this).attr({class: "activeTab"});

    $(".inactiveTab").hide();
}

function clickX() {
    $(this).parent().attr({class: "inactiveTab"});
    $(".inactiveTab").show();

    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

What it does it, change the style of a div when clicked and hides all other divs from the class. When someone clicks the x that's inside the div, it should change the style back and show the hidden divs.

Comment: You've an inline handler?

Comment: @Teemu I´m not sure what you mean by inline handler, but if by inline handler you mean something like onClick="", no I don´t

Comment: Yes, I meant `onXXXX` attribute in HTML code. Please show the function from the beginning and how you're calling it.

Comment: `window.event` is undefined on firefox. You should provide more context regarding your question.

Comment: @Teemu and @ A. Wolff I edited the post to show the code

Comment: Well `e` is not defined! Hence the error.

Comment: `e` is not within the argument list. `var` will hoist the declaration of `e`, and you'll get `undefined`.

Comment: @Smiley You have to pass `event` as function parameter. So how do you bind this event?

Comment: It should be `function clickX(e)` because the event is passed as a parameter. Don't bother with the `window.event` crap, because jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: `clickX()` should be `clickX(e)`

Comment: Thank you all for the help!!! I was able to solve it thanks to you all, thanks a lot :)

Comment: My friend has this error on social network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e is not defined so that would be the error

```
function clickX(e) {  //e needs to be in the arguments as long as the event is attached properly, this will work.
    $(this).parent().attr({class: "inactiveTab"});
    $(".inactiveTab").show();

    e = e || window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

If you used jQuery to attach the event, there is no reason to be doing the check for event or stopPropagation.

Comment: What could be then the purpose of `e = e || window.event;` because anyway `window.event` isn't defined on FF, using `new Event(type)`?

Comment: Really @A.Wolff ? That has been the way to do it since the time of document.layers and NN4 days.

Comment: If `e` parameter is undefined, it would still be on FF. I think the most confusing is getting what OP is expecting here using his code

Comment: it's [Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#Attach_event_handlers) stuff

Comment: `e` will be defined on FF, check is only to support older IE, am I correct?

Comment: I guess yes, but if the event is wrapped with jquery, `e` should be defined anyway ?

Comment: Yes, real browsers pass in the event details as an argument. MS used the model of using a special property to hold the last event that took place. And that special property design causes a lot of fun and dealing with multiple events :) And if the person used jQuery to do this, than all of the checks are useless since jQuery did all the normalization/polyfill for the developer already.